# CSS background doesn't fit properly / is cut off

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-float

I have the problem that my background suddenly cuts off. It worked normally before on chrome, but now I cuts off in the middle of the page (http://prntscr.com/kwsaxn).

My CSS Code:

```
html, body {
background: url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover; 
}
```

Executed in the header:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

I don't seem to find any options online how to solve that, but maybe it's as simple as in my last questions and I'm just missing something.

Maybe it has something to do that the  is called right where it ends, but I had it like that before when it still worked.

PS: I tested it on edge, chrome and my iphone safari.

Thanks :)

Comment: The `html` and `body` elements might not be filling the whole screen, depending on how you're positioning the child elements (like the "server statistik" column). Have you tried highlighting the `<html>` or `<body>` tags in the developer tools to see what their bounds are?

Comment: They are not very big, but the picture gets cut off inside them (the html/body tags are bigger than the image)

Comment: Try making background-size:100%, background-position: center center. Hope that will work

Comment: Nothing changes, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please give the link of website or codepen editor

Comment: bro you have to change the image.image height not good thats why this happen.here is the link of image you can see it  [link](https://www.playinfinity.de/webpanel/images/background.jpg) ...its height too short to fit in browser sacreen.image creating problem.change the image

Comment: Thanks. I reuploaded the image from my pc, but I never changed it. Sorry, but I didn't thought there was a problem with the picture :D